# Virtual Host Apache2 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to set up a VH on apache2 so i've created the file *"mysite.conf"* like this

```
<Virtual Host *:80>
    ServerName mysite.net
    ServerAlias www.mysite.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webmaster_home

    ErrorLog [...]
    CustomLog [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

and all works fine untill I decided to move my site in a new dir named *"mysite.net"*. So I modified my *"mysite.conf"*:

```
<Virtual Host *:80>
    ServerName mysite.net
    ServerAlias www.mysite.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webmaster_home/mysite.net

    ErrorLog [...]
    CustomLog [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

and my site stop works. The log file reported:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable    configuartion error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if    necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
AH00121: r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/webmaster_home/index.php  
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php
```

After Googling my problem it results in an error of my *"mysite.conf"*, wich should include:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/webmaster_home>
        Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Done that I tried again and a new error came out reporting

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

and looking at the log file it reports:

```
AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are bot off, so the  
RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to   
circumvent directory restrictions
```

So if I set up *FollowSymLinks* or *SymLinksIfOwnerMatch* I get a loop, if I don't my user can't access the directory.

---

If it will be useful, this is my *"apache2.conf"*

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLink
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

---

And my /var/www/webmaster_home/.htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <ifModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </ifModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting enviroments,  
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Black liste protected files
    ##
    RewriteRule themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders and files
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ico
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpeg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.gif
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.less
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.scss
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.pdf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.swf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.txt
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xls
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.eot
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ttf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.svg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wmv
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.avi
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mov
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp4
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.webm
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ogg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !docs/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !themes/.*
    RewriteCOnd ^ index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</ifModule>
```

---

And this is my directories tree:

```
/var
|----www/
     |----webmaster_home/
          |----mysite.net/
          |----logs/
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this by moving .htaccess in mysite.net/ from webmaster_home/
When I moved entire sito from previous dir the hidden files weren't moved with the rest of the files.